# How to find if a string contains "ONLY" Special characters in java

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

Suppose I define a String as:

```
String splChrs      = "/-@#$%^&_-+=()" ;

String inputString = getInputString();  //gets a String from end the user
```

I want to check if String "*inputString*" contains **ONLY** special characters contained in String "*splChrs*" 
i.e. I want to set a boolean flag as **true** if *inputString* contained only characters present in "*splChrs*"

```
eg:  String inputString = "#######@";  //set boolean flag=true
```

And boolean flag is set as **false** if it contained any letters that did not contain in "*splChrs*"

```
eg:  String inputString = "######abc"; //set boolean flag=false
```

Comment: String.matches("[/-@#$%^&_-+=()]+") will do it for you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
String splChrs = "-/@#$%^&_+=()" ;
boolean found = inputString.matches("[" + splChrs + "]+");
```

**PS:** I have rearranged your characters in `splChrs` variable to make sure hyphen is at starting to avoid escaping. I also removed a redundant (and problematic) hyphen from middle of the string which would otherwise give different meaning to character class (denoted range).

Thanks to @AlanMoore for this note about character in character class:

`^` if it's listed first; ] if it's not listed first; `[` anywhere; and `&` if it's followed immediately by another `&`.

Comment: You might have mentioned that you also removed an *extra* hyphen; I had to discover it the hard way. :P  But hyphen just one of several characters that can give you trouble.  Others are: `^` if it's listed first; `]` if it's *not* listed first; `[` anywhere; and `&` if it's followed immediately by another `&`.  I know square brackets weren't included in the example, but it was just an example.  You should at least get a ruling.

Comment: Yes forgot to mention about removal of redundant (and problematic) hyphen from middle. Rest I checked in the string if there is any other character that may need escaping but found no other case.

Comment: Good suggestion Alan, but what if i want to include "[" ?

Comment: @shwetha: It would be: `splChrs = "-\\[/@#$%^&_+=()";`

Comment: Sorry, have another thing cropping up my mind. what about "\" ?

Comment: The easiest, safest way to do this is to escape everything: `splChars = splChars.replaceAll(".", "\\\\$0");`.  (I am of course assuming there are only special characters in `splChrs`.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if(inputString.matches("[" + splChrs + "]+")){

// set bool to true
}else{

// set bool to false
}
```

Comment: See my comment under [anubhava's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24138416/20938) about the many potential problems with this anwer.

Answer (score 1):

don't invent bicycle, 'cause all those tasks are common mostly to everyone.
I suggest using Apache Commons lib where it's possible:
[http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#containsOnly%28java.lang.String,%20char[]%29](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#containsOnly%28java.lang.String,%20char%5b%5d%29)

---

containsOnly

public static boolean containsOnly(String str,
                                   char[] valid)

```
Checks if the String contains only certain characters.

A null String will return false. A null valid character array will return false. An empty String (length()=0) always returns true.

 StringUtils.containsOnly(null, *)       = false
 StringUtils.containsOnly(*, null)       = false
 StringUtils.containsOnly("", *)         = true
 StringUtils.containsOnly("ab", '')      = false
 StringUtils.containsOnly("abab", 'abc') = true
 StringUtils.containsOnly("ab1", 'abc')  = false
 StringUtils.containsOnly("abz", 'abc')  = false


Parameters:
    str - the String to check, may be null
    valid - an array of valid chars, may be null 
Returns:
    true if it only contains valid chars and is non-null
```

Comment: A Useful link about StringUtils!